# OLEDB Command transformation does not update multiple columns in one query

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, lookup, oledbcommand

I have a very peculiar situation. I am trying to update a table in SQL Server through an OLEDB Command. The source for the package is an OLEDB Source with a SQL Query that references the table itself i.e. the source and the destination are the same although the source joins to other tables and is part of a complex query.

The source produces a few rows which are looked up on a particular column. If the lookup results in a match, then I need to update a few columns for the matched rows. So the structure is:

```
OLEDB SOURCE (Query that produces the values that will be used to update the table in OLEDB Destination)

LOOKUP

oledb command (update).
```

But the problem that I am facing is quite odd. When I write a query to update all the fields, the table does not get updated. If I write the query to update a single column only, it works. So in effect:

```
update table set field1 = ?, field2 = ?, field3 = ?, field4 = ? where MatchingColumn = ?
```

does not work.
But

```
update table set field1 = ? where MatchingColumn = ?
```

Works. Is it something that I am doing wrong or is this a known issue?

Comment: Just want to know 1 thing, through this, what are you updating?. Is it some kind of flag update?

Comment: if the second one works but the first one doesnt i'm thinking your number of parameters is off.

Comment: I agree with @Tristan.  Check the parameter mapping.  Your key column should be mapped to parameter4 (0 based numbering)

Comment: @JithinShaji I am updating 5 columns which hold different text values. For example, if I were looking up Person, I'd be updating their Department, SubDepartmentName, Manager and etc. No flag updates. Tristan and Mark, I tried mapping them one by one just to make sure that I am no mis-matching the number of params.

Comment: Have you tried starting with second update (which works) and adding one column/parameter at a time to see when it breaks?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes. Since I have to update 5 columns, I added 5 different OLEDB Commands and each one of them updates only 1 column at a time. This(5 OLEDB Commands) works fine and updates appropriately. I tried changing one of them to update just 2 columns and it bonkers out. It finishes successfully, but does not update anything on the table.

Comment: Next thing I would do is start a profile trace, run the package with the multi-column update that fails, and look at what actual SQL command is being passed from the package.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I will try that and see if it helps.